# AngularJS routing paths to Express server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I am a beginner to AngularJS, Node and Express.
I can't get even the most basic routing to work with $http.get or $http.post.
Every example I have found online leaves out the relationship between the filenames, the Angular controller path, and the route path in the server.  They just show the code without showing the paths and filenames.

Here is my html file: "/programs/static/example.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="exampleController">
        <input type="submit" value="Click me" ng-click="request()">
    </div> 
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/example-controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Angular controller: "/programs/static/js/example-controller.js"

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope) {

    $scope.request = function() {
        data="test";
        $http.post("/" , data);
    };

});
```

And here is my NodeJS server: "/programs/node-server.js"

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static('./static'));

app.post('/example.html/', function(req, res){
    console.log("request received.");
});


app.listen(80);
```

The problem is that the console of my server doesn't display "request received." This is an example app I built just to post this to Stack Overflow. In my real app I have tried as many different routes as possible. I can get app.get() in my node server to work using simple URLs (not $http methods). But it is obvious from my testing that my Angular controller isn't sending any requests, or else the server isn't receiving them.

Comment: Inject $http dependency in your controller: exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $http)...

Comment: It would help us a lot if you actually told us what the problem is. What is not working? What are the error messages(if any). Include error messages for both AngularJS (in browser dev tools) AND Express server

Comment: @RicardoTribaldos I added the dependency, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash The problem is that the console of my server doesn't display "request received."  This is an example app I built just to post this to Stack Overflow.  In my real app I have tried as many different routes as possible.  I can get app.get() in my node server to work using simple URLs (not $http methods).  But it is obvious from my testing that my Angular controller isn't sending any requests, or else the server isn't receiving them.

Comment: If you have more information, edit your original question. Don't add it to comments. Comments are not as visible as your question, and this will help others to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST endpoint should not have a file extension in it's name. Any posts to `"example.html"` will try to return an actual html file named `example.html` if you have any such file name in your `\static` folder. Your API endpoints should have clear unique names, with no file extension:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
  console.log("request received.");
});
```

When using `$http.post` and passing `"/"` as the parameter, the actual URL that is posted to will be relative to your current URL. You should always use an absolute URL when posting to a server (unless you know what you are doing). You should also implement the `.then` and `.catch` methods. These will help you debug the problem:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:8080/test", data).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);  //this will log a success
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);  //this will log the error
});
```

You are also forgot to inject the `$http` provider in your controller:

```
exampleApp.controller('exampleController', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation.  I tried what you said.  However, I am sure my problem has to do with my endpoints, such as '/test' in app.post() or 'localhost/example.html/test' in $http.post().  
I tried what you said, and there were 0 messages published to the console.  Nothing.  No errors, no success messages.  I'm doing something wrong, and I don't know what it is.

Comment: Which console? You need to be as specific as humanly possible. Is this the Express console, or the dev tools in your web browser?

Comment: Also, I included my paths and filenames in my original post because I know that this is where the problem lies.

Comment: I believe you should do {{request()}}, that's how you access $scope in angular

Comment: Now change both the `$http.post("http://localhost/test", data)` and `app.post('/test', function(req,res)` and it should still work

Comment: I don't recommend making `$http` requests to `"/"`, since you are also serving static assets from that route. A good practice is to prefix all `$http` routes with `"/api"` like `app.post("/api/test")`

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment.  I was trying to edit it to clarify and it was 5 minutes old.  I got the Express console to print "request received" by using `$http.post("http://localhost/", data) and `app.post('/', function(req, res)`.  However, I can't get it to send the data.

Comment: I got it to work.  Thank you @Pop-A-Stash.  I marked your answer as the solution.